# Get events that my friends and I are attending

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just hoping for a bit of help with some SQL. I'm fairly new to MySQL.

I am using Code Igniter if that helps, but generally the SQL will be good enough. I'll ignore Active Record.

I have a few tables which I guess will be used:

```
Users
id
first_name
last_name
username

Events
id
created_by_user_id
name
start_date
start_time
end_date
end_time

Attendees
id
user_id
event_id

Friends
user_id
friend_id
approved
```

So when I am after is:

Get all results that:

- My approved friends and I are attending
- Upcoming events, haven't passed the end_date/end_time
- Order by start_date & start_time

I'll need to JOIN the users table onto the this, so I can have something like this in the View:

```
<?= foreach($events as $e): ?>
    <?= $e->name; ?> created by <?=$e->first_name . ' ' . $e->last_name; ?>
    Happening: <?= $e->start_date; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Ran into any specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend to restructure the Events and join the fields start_date/start_time and end_date/end_time with start/finish with a TIMESTAMP type.

So for the first question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.event_id 
 FROM Attendees a1, Attendees a2 
 WHERE  
   a1.id = a2.id  
   AND a1.user_id = ${USER_ID} 
   AND a2.user_id IN 
         (SELECT friends_id FROM 
           Friends WHERE approved = True 
           AND user_id = ${USER_ID});
```

Or you can use the INTERSECT whatever is more easy for you.

The solution for the second question, if you merge the date/time attributes:

```
SELECT id FROM Events WHERE end < NOW();
```

Third query:

```
SELECT id from Events ORDER BY start;
```

Comment: Thanks. I imagine it would be similar if I wanted to get the events my friends and I had made, following the same conditions above? How would I bundle all your queries together above? And JOINing.. Is that easily done with the multiple tables there? What about id being in there twice, three times, for attendees, events, users, events, etc. anyway to make it so users.* AS creator.*??